# FLUTTER CON GETX: Actualizar la longitud del tabController

Tags: flutter, controller, get, animación, tab

yo actualmente tengo una pagina que al entrar crea una intancia de tabController mediante el metodo  **onInit** que provee Getx en sus controladores

```
class ReadbookController extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabCtrl;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    tabCtrl = TabController(length: 10,vsync: this);
    super.onInit();
  }

  void reloadPage() {
    tabCtrl = TabController(length: 20, vsync: this); // cambia la longitud del tabcontroller
    update(['reload_page']); // actualiza la pagina con la nueva longitud
  }
}
```

el metodo **reloadPage** lo uso con un boton para actualizar la longitud de tabController, pero me da el siguiente error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Controller's length property (50) does not match the number of tabs (40) present in TabBar's tabs property.
```

Aunque flutter es tan bueno conmigo que me la siguiente solucion

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
ReadbookController is a GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.

A GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin can only be used as a TickerProvider once.

If a State is used for multiple AnimationController objects, or if it is passed to other objects and those objects might use it more than one time in total, then instead of mixing in a GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin, use a regular GetTickerProviderStateMixin.
```

en resumen me dice que debo usar **GetTickerProviderStateMixin** en vez de usar **GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin** y cuando lo uso me actualiza sin problemas la pagina con la nueva longitud.

Pero una vez que se actualizo la nueva longitud del tabCtrl y cuando me voy a la pagina donde se muestran los **tabs** y **TabBarView** al momento de deslizar en los tabs el indicador(que esta presente en los tabs seleccionados actualmente) no se mueve es como si la animacion no funcionara, esto es algo que siempre me ah pasado cuando uso el **GetTickerProviderStateMixin**.

**Cualquier solucion se agradece**

Answer (score 1):

Anteriormente tambien estaba pensando en simplemente actualizar la pagina o volver a cargarla con los nuevos valores y por ende la nueva longitud del tabController, recientemente pude lograrlo con el siguiente codigo

```
void reloadPage(BookModel data) => Get.offNamed(
        "/book",
        arguments: data,
        preventDuplicates: false, 
      );
```

Este código reemplaza la ruta actual(pagina actual) y para los que conocen de Getx vuelve a crear e instanciar los controladores de la nueva ruta y elimina los anteriores.